SAS FILE and options RECFM=N encoding="utf-8 --> ENCODING option ignored for files opened with RECFM=N
I have code that composes XML from parts that are stored in a table in a database. I export XML via the FILE command with options RECFM=N so that CRLF characters do not appear at the end. XML is encoded in UTF-8, but sas in WLATIN2.
If I use the setting RECFM=N, then SAS prompts encoding = UTF=8. If I don't use UTF8 encoding, the XML contains invalid characters...
How to export XML in UTF8?
proc sql noprint;
select distinct PROCESS_ID
into :g_processIDList separated by ' '
from out_lib.Dbn_xml_data;
quit;

%put &g_processIDList.;


%macro DAR_XML_PROCESSING1;
    %if %length(&g_processIDList.) ne 0 %then %do;
        %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&g_processIDList., ' '));           
            %let l_processID=%scan(&g_processIDList.,&i,%str( ));
            %put processing: &l_processID.;
            
            data HELP;
                set out_lib.DBN_XML_DATA (where=(PROCESS_ID = "&l_processID."));
            run;

            proc sort data=HELP out=HELP (keep=XML_CONTENT);
            by PART_ID;
            run;

            filename out "\\somePath\&l_processID..xml" RECFM=N encoding="utf-8";
            data _null_;
              file OUT;
              set HELP;
              put XML_CONTENT;
            run;
    
        %end;   
    %end;
    %else %do;
        %put [NOTE]: nothing to process!!;
    %end;
%mend DAR_XML_PROCESSING1;

%DAR_XML_PROCESSING1;


Sounds like the source has UTF-8 characters in it? Otherwise how would the end up in the output?  Where is source dataset? You make it sound like it might be in some external database, such as ORACLE?  Are you sure the process of pulling the data into SAS is preserving the characters?

If you are running SAS using a single byte encoding then all 256 possible characters are valid.  So writing the file should not require any ENCODING setting as none of the bytes will be transformed from how they exist in the SAS character variables.
I suspect that your issue is in the step that reads the data into SAS.
If the libref being used is pointing to a SAS dataset then use ENCODING='ANY' dataset option when reading in the data.
data HELP;
  set out_lib.DBN_XML_DATA (encoding='any' where=(PROCESS_ID = "&l_processID."));
run;

If the libref being used is pointing to some external database system then you might need be running SAS using the system ENCODING option set to UTF-8.  So if you want to schedule a job make sure you schedule the job to launch SAS using that encoding

out_lib is poiting to oracle DB

If you cannot get the SAS session encoding set properly to allow UTF8 characters to flow from Oracle to SAS then use pass thru SQL to have oracle convert the UTF8 strings into something like HEX codes so they can transfer to SAS withou being run thru transcoding be either Oracle or SAS.

Check your SAS session encoding
proc options option=encoding;
run;

In Windows, the default icon "SAS 9.4 (English)" is ENCODING=WLATIN1.
Start SAS with the icon "SAS 9.4 (Unicode Support)" and the session will be running with ENCODING=UTF-8
That should make recfm=n use the session encoding.

we have default encoding wlatin2 (WINDOWS-1250). I need an automated solution, the code will be run daily as a job.

your job scheduled would be "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe" -CONFIG "C:\Program Files\SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\u8\sasv9.cfg" <your program>
